# Getting error while creating managed package from SFDX CLI

Tags: community, managed-package, error, package, second-generation-packaging

when i run this command - sf package version create --package "MY Package Name" --installation-key-bypass --codecoverage --wait 10

I get following error:

Error (1): Multiple errors occurred:
(1) Myfolder: To create email template folders, enable Folders and Enhanced Sharing.
(2) Myfolder/ET1: Cannot find folder:Myfolder
(3) Myfolder/ET2: Cannot find folder:Myfolder

My package.xml file:

```xml
<types>
        <members>EmailTemplate</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
 <types>
        <members>Myfolder</members>
        <name>EmailTemplateFolder</name>
    </types>
<types>
        <members>Myfolder/ET1</members>
        <members>Myfolder/ET2</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
<types>
```

I already tried creating package with Email templates inside public folder but it gives following error on installing the same:
[image]

MY scratch Def json:

```json
{
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "emailTemplateSettings": {
      "enableTemplateEnhancedFolderPref": true
}
  }
}
```

My SFdx project json:

```json
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "MYPackage1.1",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "",
      "apexTestAccess": {
        "permissionSets": [
          "myPackagpermission"
        ]
      }
      
    }
  ],
  "name": "orgname",
  "namespace": "orgnmspc",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "59.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "MYPackage1.1": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `package.xml` is irrelevant for 2GP. The issue is likely with you not having enabled the necessary features and settings in your config scratch def. Please [edit] to add further details including your scratch def and sfdx project JSON files.

Comment: @PhilW updated the question